# HTTP is not disabled after adding allow-http configuration in Ingress

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress, gcp-load-balancer

I have tried to block http and allow only https for the application which deployed in GCP. For the routing, using ningx ingress and tcp loadbalancer to route the traffic from client to the application.

Even after adding the below configuration in ingress yaml , still application serves http.

`kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add this annotation to already existing ingress or did you create new ingress? If you added to already existing try deleting it and deploying new ingress with this annotation.

Comment: I have added it in existing ingress and created new ingress also..It was not disabled in both cases. Master GKE version: 1.14.10-gke.42

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your issue and solved it by deleting ingress resource and deploying new one with `kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"` annotation. According to [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress-xlb#disabling_http):

> **Note:** For an existing Ingress, the HTTP load balancer resources are not deleted automatically on adding the
> `kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http`  annotation with its value set to
> `false`. A workaround for this is to delete the Ingress and recreate
> it with the annotation added. Beginning with GKE version
> 1.16.4-gke.25, the HTTP load balancer resources are automatically deleted on updating an Ingress to disable HTTP load balancing.

So if you have GKE version prior to 1.16.4-gke.25 ingress resource has to be deleted and then new ingress has to be created with this annotation.